# Function Procura Matriz in C: Comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default] Warning

Tags: c, function, pointers, compare, warnings

I'm working with matrix in C and i'm getting a warning that I can't seem to solve.

The warning is: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int procura_matriz(int **m, int numero, int y, int k){

int i, j, trueOrFalse=0;

for(i=0;i<y*k;i++){             
    if (m[i]==numero){      
        trueOrFalse=1;      
        break;
    }
}

return trueOrFalse;
}
```

Main:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int trueOrFalse;
int y=5, k=2;
int m[5][2] = {{1,2},{3,1},{5,12},{4,8},{29,10}};       
int numero =13;

trueOrFalse=procura_matriz(m, numero, y, k);

printf("\n0(Não tem numero) | 1 (Tem numero) -> %d\n", trueOrFalse);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `m` is of type `int **`, so, `m[i]` is of type `int *` and you cannot compare that with an `numero` which is an `int`, for sure.

Instead of using one index `i`, you can make use of two indexes, say, `i` and `j` controlled by `y` and `k`, in your function.

Comment: I changed the code to 2 loops and I tried to "get the number" in two different ways.                                                                                                            

for (i = 0; i < y; i++) {
 for (j = 0; j < k; j++){
  if (m[i][j]==numero){  
   trueOrFalse=1;  
   break;
  }
 } 
}

Comment: The other way is, instead of having "m [i] [j]" I tried with "(* (* (m + i) + j))" but still with errors.

Answer (score 0):

M is a 2d array. M[i] is an array. And you compare an array with a integer, so you get the warning.
Change m[i] to m[i/y][i%y] to resolve

Comment: I changed the code to 2 loops and "tried to get the number" with "m[i][j]" but now the error is "Segmentation Fault". The code-> for (i = 0; i < y; i++) { for (j = 0; j < k; j++){ if (m[i][j]==numero){ trueOrFalse=1; break; } } }

Comment: I dont see problem in your code. You can add printf function to print m[i][j] to debug and tell me the output